# how to get string font from UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I get the text font of a segment in a UISegmentedControl?
When the titleAtrributedString was not settled.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this extension for you to be able to modify font in your segmented control :

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func setFont(name:String?, size:CGFloat?) {
        let attributedSegmentFont = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: name!, size: size!)!, forKey: NSAttributedStringKey.font as NSCopying)
        setTitleTextAttributes(attributedSegmentFont as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: .normal)
    }
}
```

You can use it on your code as:

```
segmentedControl?.setFont(name: "My Font Name", size: 12)
```

Comment: but i don't want to set the font. I want to get the font. thanks any way.